# are android actions done in order as written in onCreate?

Tags: android, oncreate

I want to know if these actions are done in order or not inside on create

```
     mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game.swf");

    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is yes.

Comment: can I seperate them with a bit of time ?

Comment: I have not worked with WebViews yet but if there is a way to check if the loadUrl method is done then just begin the next step. Or maybe a sleep statement. Also my other comment meant to be "in order". My bad.

Comment: No, you should *never* block the UI thread (which is what is running `onCreate()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Statements within the body of a Java method will execute sequentially.